# What's the difference between these For loops that makes one crash?

Tags: javascript

This is from Codecademy's Javascript lesson "Search Text For Your Name". The following works:

```
var text = "My name is Zorak. Everyone calls me Zorak.";
var myName = "Zorak";
var hits = [];

for ( i=0; i < text.length; i++ ){
    if (text[i] === myName[0]) {
        for (var j = i; j < i + myName.length; j++) {
            hits.push(text[j])
        }       
    }
}
```

However, when I replace `i + myName.length` with `j + myName.length`, it's crashing. In full:

```
var text = "My name is Zorak. Everyone calls me Zorak.";
var myName = "Zorak";
var hits = [];

for ( i=0; i < text.length; i++ ){
    if (text[i] === myName[0]) {
        for (var j = i; j < j + myName.length; j++) {
            hits.push(text[j])
        }       
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors when I run this, which led me to believe that it's just stuck in an infinite loop, except that when I place a console.log marker within the For loop in question, it doesn't print anything.

What's the reason for it crashing?

Comment: What do you expect from that change? Randomly modifying code rarely leads to sensible results...

Comment: It's an infinite loop.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i expect to make it not crash. the 'j < j' example was what I'd been working with for a while, but couldn't make work. I switched it to 'j < i' to see what would happen, and it worked. I knew it had something to do with that portion of the code, because I tried constants that worked. Yes, randomly modifying code rarely leads to sensible results, but certainly it must be worthwhile to compare what works to what doesn't work in an effort to discover why, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes because it's an infinite loop.

Here is your second example, with the static variables converted to their values:

```
var text = "My name is Zorak. Everyone calls me Zorak.";
var myName = "Zorak";
var hits = [];

for (i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
  if (text[i] === 'Z') {
    for (var j = i; j < j + 5; j++) {
      hits.push(text[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Specifically, your inner `for` condition is causing the infinite loop:

```
for (var j = i; j < j + myName.length; j++) {
```

or with `myName.length` replaced by its value, 5:

```
for (var j = i; j < j + 5; j++) {
```

`j` will always be less than `j + 5` so the loop continues without end, consuming memory until crash.

Comment: "j will always be less than j + 5" -- so obvious, but didn't hit me until you put it like this!

Answer (score 2):

```
j < j + myName.length; j++
```

`j` never reaches the end. You're incrementing it, but you compare it against number that is always larger than itself (assuming `myName.length` is `> 0`). The conditions for the loop is always satisfied, causing it to run forever.